# Automatically add extra row to SUM, when added to the first row or last row in section (or summarise until empty cell)

Tags: google-sheets

**TL;DR:** How do I make a summarise-cell, that automatically sums from itself until an empty cell?

---

I'm working on a budget, looking like this:

[image: SUM section]

It has happened several times, where I've added a new row in the bottom, but forgotten to adjust the `=SUM(...)`-cell, to include the new row. Like this:

[image: Add new row to SUM]

Since when I add the new rows, I like to add them in the top or in the bottom.

How do I get my cell to automatically add newly added row to the sum?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to DYNAMICALLY expand the range to be added, so this is better:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B4:B" & MATCH("daily stuff", A1:A, 0) -1 ))
```

which will take into account any other cell of `column B` that will precede the "daily stuff" group

[image: sum]

Answer (score -1):

Change the `=SUM(...)`-statement, to include the empty cell in the bottom.

When adding a new row, right-click row 5, and select 'Add row below'.

That way, when a new row is added, then a new cell is added in the middle of the range. And then Google Sheets can figure out that add that to the `=SUM`:

[image: automatically sum until empty cell]

Comment: ... but then, next time, you will find yourself with the same problem.

Comment: Ahh... I forgot to add an essential part of this 'hack' (to right click row 5 and add a new row below). Otherwise you'd be right.